# Converting hex to decimal in MIPS

Tags: java, mips

how would i convert this Java code into MIPS? I am having a hard time especially implementing the idea of "bases" in MIPS. how would i go about using mips and figuring out what base it is?
for example lets say we have 0xFFF, 0x3C, 0xAA

what would it look like?

```
// Function to convert hexadecimal to decimal 
    static int hexadecimalToDecimal(String hexVal) 
    {    
        int len = hexVal.length(); 

        // Initializing base value to 1, i.e 16^0 
        int base = 1; 

        int dec_val = 0; 

        // Extracting characters as digits from last character 
        for (int i=len-1; i>=0; i--) 
        {    
            // if character lies in '0'-'9', converting  
            // it to integral 0-9 by subtracting 48 from 
            // ASCII value 
            if (hexVal.charAt(i) >= '0' && hexVal.charAt(i) <= '9') 
            { 
                dec_val += (hexVal.charAt(i) - 48)*base; 

                // incrementing base by power 
                base = base * 16; 
            } 

            // if character lies in 'A'-'F' , converting  
            // it to integral 10 - 15 by subtracting 55  
            // from ASCII value 
            else if (hexVal.charAt(i) >= 'A' && hexVal.charAt(i) <= 'F') 
            { 
                dec_val += (hexVal.charAt(i) - 55)*base; 

                // incrementing base by power 
                base = base*16; 
            } 
        } 
        return dec_val; 
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the Java code you've posted that involves _"figuring out what base it is"_. The function just assumes that the input is a base16 string.

Comment: @Michael for example if the input was 1A, how would i know that A is base 0 and 1 is base 1

Comment: _"A is base 0 and 1 is base 1"_. That makes no sense. You seem to have misunderstood what [the term _base_ means](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(mathematics)). In any case, why don't you just translate the Java code as it is?

Comment: If you want to translate this code that you found into assembly language, you'd be better off starting with the C version than the Java version: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-hexadecimal-to-decimal/